# Java - make object with name form String

Tags: java

my program will have lots of objects, that will contain Strings, booleans and other, and I want to call them with IDs. So I want something like:

```
int ID = 1;
void add_object()
{ 
String IDstring = Integer.toString(ID);
myobject IDstring = new myobject();
ID++;
}
```

How should I make this working? Or is there any better way to make this?

Comment: You could use an accordant data structure like `Map<Key, Value>`

Comment: I've never heard about it, can you please send me link about it?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a class named `Foo`. This class might be your model, where you store all your strings, booleans and so on:

```
public class Foo {

    private final int id;

    public Foo(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "[id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

In addition you have another class name `Bar`, where you have your map:

```
public class Bar {

    private final Map<Integer, Foo> map;

    public Bar() {
        map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(0, new Foo(0));
        map.put(5, new Foo(5));
        map.put(6, new Foo(6));
    }

    private void list() {
        System.out.println(map.get(0).toString());
        System.out.println(map.get(5).toString());
        System.out.println(map.get(6).toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.list();
    }
}
```

I have added three objects to the map with the accordant id's. Within `list()` I print these objects.

I hope this helps you to start with.

Take a look here to read more about maps: [public interface Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Edit: you can of course use a string to store the id.